# urxvt doesn't show glyphs on Arch linux new install

Tags: arch-linux, rxvt

My new install of Arch is not displaying any gylphs/icons in urxvt.

```
! ******************
! urxvt config
! ******************

URxvt*imLocale: en_US.UTF-8

URxvt*termName: rxvt
URxvt*depth: 24
URxvt*geometry: 90x30
URxvt*transparent: false
URxvt*fading: 0
URxvt*loginShell: true
! scrollback buffer lines - 65535 is max on most machines (64 is default)
URxvt*saveLines: 65535
URxvt*internalBorder: 3
URxvt*lineSpace: 0

! Fonts
URxvt*font: xft:Source Code Pro for Powerline:size=12
URxvt.letterSpace: 0
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight

! Scrollbar
URxvt*scrollBar: false

! Disable Perl extension
! If you do not use the Perl extension features, you can improve the security
! and speed by disabling Perl extensions completely. 
!URxvt.perl-ext:
!URxvt.perl-ext-common:

! -- Fonts -- !

!URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:autohint=true:size=12,xft:Inconsolata\ for\ Powerline:autohint=true:size=12

!URxvt*font: xft:SourceCodePro+Powerline+Awesome+Regular:autohint=true:size=10
!URxvt*font: xft:Source\ Code\ Pro\ Medium:pixelsize=13:antialias=true:hinting=true,xft:Source\ Code\ Pro\ Medium:pixelsize=13:antialias=true:hinting=true

!URxvt*font:                 xft:Inconsolata for Powerline:pixelsize=27:minspace=False, xft:DejaVu Sans:pixelsize=18
!URxvt*boldFont:             xft:Inconsolata Bold for Powerline:pixelsize=27:minspace=False, xft:DejaVu Sans:pixelsize=18
!


! special
*.foreground:   #d8dee9
*.background:   #1d1f21
*.cursorColor:  #d8dee9

! black
*.color0:       #2d2d2d
*.color8:       #444444

! red
*.color1:       #ed0b0b
*.color9:       #b55454

! green
*.color2:       #40a62f
*.color10:      #78a670

! yellow
*.color3:       #f2e635
*.color11:      #faf380

! blue
*.color4:       #327bd1
*.color12:      #68a7d4

! magenta
*.color5:       #b30ad0
*.color13:      #c583d0

! cyan
*.color6:       #32d0fc
*.color14:      #8adaf1

! white
*.color7:       #555555
*.color15:      #e0e3e7

! *****************
! Copy and Paste 
! *****************
!  URxvt.clipboard.autocopy: true
!  URxvt.keysym.M-c: perl:clipboard:copy
!  URxvt.keysym.M-v: perl:clipboard:paste

! Disable ISO 14755 unicode input so we can use Ctrl-Shift bindings
URxvt.iso14755:        false
URxvt.iso14755_52:     false

! Disable Ctrl-Alt-c & Ctrl-Alt-v bindings (optional)
URxvt.keysym.C-M-c:    builtin-string:
URxvt.keysym.C-M-v:    builtin-string:

! Bind Ctrl-Shift-c & Ctrl-Shift-v to copy and paste
! I dont know why, but I needed to use hex keysym values to get it to work
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x43: eval:selection_to_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x56: eval:paste_clipboard

! ***********End Copy and paste*******

! ******************
! /urxvt config
! ******************
```

other terminals (Termite) show the icons without any problems
[image]

I am only using i3 window manager with ZSH as my default shell.
executing
`fc-list | grep "Source Code Pro for Powerline"` returns the expected results

```
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Regular
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Black for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Black:style=Black,Regular
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline SemiboldItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Semibold:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Medium for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline BoldItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro ExtraLight for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro ExtraLight for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline Italic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline SemiboldItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Semibold:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Medium for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Medium for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline MediumItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline BoldItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline LightItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline MediumItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Bold for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Bold for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Bold
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline Italic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Light for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Regular
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Black for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Black:style=Black,Regular
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Light for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Semibold for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Semibold:style=Semibold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Black for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Black:style=Black,Regular
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline BlackItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline SemiboldItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Semibold:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline BlackItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline LightItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline BlackItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline MediumItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Light for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light,Regular
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline ExtraLightItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Semibold for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Semibold:style=Semibold,Regular
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline ExtraLightItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro ExtraLight for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Source Code Pro Powerline ExtraLightItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Bold for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Bold
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Semibold for Powerline.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Semibold:style=Semibold,Regular
/home/sammy/.local/share/fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline Italic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline LightItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/home/sammy/.fonts/Source Code Pro Powerline BoldItalic.otf: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
```

I am executing `xrdb -m ~/.Xresources` after every change to the .Xresources

Edit: The output in the screen captures is generated by using ls as an exa alias which depends on Nerd fonts as I already have them installed

`fc-list | grep "Nerd"`

```
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Light Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Black Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Black Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Semibold Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Semibold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Bold Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Semibold Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Light Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Bold Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Medium Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Medium Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro ExtraLight Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Bold Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Medium Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Light Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Bold Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro ExtraLight Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Black Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Black Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Black Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro ExtraLight Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Medium Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Black Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Semibold Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro ExtraLight Italic Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Semibold Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Semibold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Sauce Code Pro Light Italic Nerd Font Complete.ttf: SauceCodePro Nerd Font:style=Light Italic,Italic
```

Comment: Does urxvt support these? What is the tool you are running there? I have never seen something like this in a terminal, is this some sort of modified `ls`?

Comment: @terdon, I have aliased ls to exa https://the.exa.website/ but urxvt shows the same messy prompt regardless of the executed command, including oh my zsh with powerline installed.

Comment: I just realized you are writing `urxvt` and not `rxvt`, which I assume means you are using [`rxvt-unicode`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/urxvt.1) and that is, presumably, theoretically capable of displaying these glyphs. Can you please confirm that you have in the past seen this specific terminal display such characters, just so we can be sure it's theoretically possible?

Comment: You are correct, I am using rxvt-unicode. In fact I tried multiple versions including rxvt-unicode-truecolor-wide-glyphs. I have seen multiple people using urxvt with gyphs showing without any problems but I have never had it working myself. I tried to correct the tag to use urxvt instead of rxvt but it keeps default back to rxvt when I save editing the post

Comment: Well, does it work in other contexts? What happens if you just paste `☺` into your `urxvt`. Is that displayed correctly?

Comment: It actually paste a question mark instead

Comment: OK. Please add all this info to your question (no need to add "Edit:", just edit it in as though it had been there from the beginning). We now know that the problem is how to get urxvt to display UTF8 in general. The next thing to check is whether your `Source Code Pro` font supports them. I don't quite understand what the `Nerd` fonts have to do with it, they are `Sauce Code` not `Source Code` so are not what you are using in the urxvt config.

Comment: That was a typo but that line is commented out.
I usually try fonts using urxvt -fn 'xft:{FONT_TO_TRY}:pixelsize=12' instead of editing the .Xresources file every time I try a different font.

Thanks for trying to helo by the way

Comment: No, I mean your rxvt is using the `Source Code Pro` fonts. But then you say "The output in the screen captures [...] depends on Nerd fonts" but you are not using these Nerd fonts since those are `Sauce Code`. So are you _sure_ that your chosen font family, the `Source Code` ones can display unicode? Can you display glyphs using that font in any program?

Comment: What font is urxvt actually using?  What does urxvt try to use by default?  It's obvious that two different fonts are being used... the "correct" one has slashed zeroes, the "incorrect" one has dotted zeroes.

Comment: Does an "xft:" font specification require you to escape the spaces?  The only one not commented out does not escape them.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what was causing the Glyphs/Icons not to show in URxvt.
Even though I had setup the machine using `en_CA.utf8`, I had to also add en_US.utf8 to enable UTF-8 in URxvt.
Executing the following command resolved all UTF-8 related issues in URxvt:

`localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Using the below .Xresources file, solves all problems

```
! special colors
*.foreground:  #a39e9b
*.background:  #2f1e2e
*.cursorColor:  #a39e9b
! black
*.color0:      #2f1e2e
*.color8:      #776e71
! red
*.color1:      #ef6155
*.color9:      #ef6155
! green
*.color2:      #48b685
*.color10:     #48b685
! yellow
*.color3:      #fec418
*.color11:     #fec418
! blue
*.color4:      #06b6ef
*.color12:     #06b6ef
! magenta
*.color5:      #815ba4
*.color13:     #815ba4
! cyan
*.color6:      #5bc4bf
*.color14:     #5bc4bf
! white
*.color7:      #a39e9b
*.color15:     #e7e9db

! Urxvt Specific Settings

URxvt*scrollBar:         false
URxvt*scrollBar_right:   false
URxvt.iso14755: false
URxvt.font: xft:MesloLGS Nerd Font:autohint=true:size=12,xft:TerminessTTFNerdFontMono:size=12

*antialias:  true
*autohint:   true

! Restore Ctrl+Shift+(c|v)
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-V: eval:paste_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-C: eval:selection_to_clipboard
!URxvt.iso14755: false
URxvt.iso14755_52: false

! Common navigation  Keybinds

URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down: command:\033]721;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Control-Up: \033[1;5A
URxvt.keysym.Control-Down: \033[1;5B
URxvt.keysym.Control-Right: \033[1;5C
URxvt.keysym.Control-Left: \033[1;5D

!! Copy, Paste + More

URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,clipboard,url-select,keyboard-select
URxvt.keysym.M-Escape: perl:keyboard-select:activate
URxvt.keysym.M-s: perl:keyboard-select:search
URxvt.keysym.M-u: perl:url-select:select_next
URxvt.urlLauncher: firefox
URxvt.underlineURLs: true
URxvt.urlButton: 2 
URxvt.url-select.autocopy:true
```

Thanks @terdon & @Marc Wilson for their help.